# Find the start and end of a redirect chain

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table of URL redirects in a SQL server table, each redirect has an ID, a FromURL and a ToURL field.

I've been asked to find where we have a chain of redirects in the table so that we can replace them with a single redirect so that users are only redirected once rather than multiple times.

An example of the table is below:

[image: Sample Table]

As you can see, if a user visits URL A, they will be redirected to B, then from B to C then from C to D we'd like to replace this with a single redirect from A to D to speed up the page load.

I thought I might be able to do this without cursors with a recursive CTE but I got completely stuck with this, the best I managed to to was find the start of each chain with the following:

```
SELECT  r.ID ,
        r.FromURL ,
        r.ToURL
FROM    dbo.redirect r
WHERE   fromURL NOT IN ( SELECT ToURL
                         FROM   dbo.redirect r2 )
```

This gives me the start of the chains (or the ones that aren't in a chain at all) by selecting any records where the FromURL hasn't been redirected by any other redirect.  When I tried following through some of the recursive CTE examples, all I ended up with was junk data or hitting the recursion limit.

Ideally what I'd like to get out of this is data similar to the following:

[image: Ideal result]

As you can see, the chains of redirects have been replaced with a single one, so every level in the hierarchy now goes directly to the end of the chain.

I'm just a DBA who agreed to do something for our web team that I have now found completely out of my ability with T-SQL so if anyone can help me out that would be most appreciated.

Comment: Can you pull down the table and do it in a different language?

Comment: Yeah, I don't see why not, if it's easier to do in some other language then I'm happy to have a look at it, the only other language that I'm personally familiar with is C# (mostly through SQL CLR procedures), but I'm always willing to try something new :-)

Comment: You could use c# and build a directed graph. Then I assume you'll end up with disconnected lines. Find all nodes that have nothing pointing to them, and compress each line, storing all intermediate nodes at the beginning. This assumes you can have this thing remain in memory or be accessed quickly so you dont have to recompute it.

Comment: There are optimizations that might need to be done.

Comment: http://hansolav.net/sql/graphs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution can be found searching for: "Directed Acyclic Graph", "Traversal", "SQL".  [hansolav.net/sql/graphs.html#topologicalsorting](http://hansolav.net/sql/graphs.html#topologicalsorting) has some good info.

If you need a fast answer, here's a quick-and-dirty method.  It's not efficient, and it needs an acyclic input, but it's readable to someone not familiar with sql.

```
SELECT id, FromUrl, ToUrl
INTO #temp
FROM dbo.redirect

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
  UPDATE cur
  SET ToUrl = nxt.ToURL
  FROM #temp cur
  INNER JOIN #temp nxt ON (cur.ToURL = nxt.FromURL)
END

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Alternatively, with a recursive CTE:

```
;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 1 as redirect_count, id, FromURL, ToUrl
  FROM dbo.redirect
  UNION ALL
  SELECT redirect_count + 1, cur.id, cur.FromURL, nxt.ToURL
  FROM cte cur
  INNER JOIN @t nxt ON (cur.ToURL = nxt.FromURL)
)
SELECT
  t1.id, t2.FromUrl, t2.ToUrl
FROM dbo.redirect t1
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 FromUrl, ToUrl
  FROM cte
  WHERE id = t1.id
  ORDER BY redirect_count DESC
) t2
```

Comment: Cheers for that link, looks really interesting and useful, I'll have a look at that and the queries tomorrow and let you know how I get on.